# I'm trying to search a directory and it's sub-directories to check if the filename includes the strings I have

Tags: python

I have an excel file which with a bit of cleaning, will give me a column of strings. I'm trying to search in a directory with a given path and all its sub-directories to find all files with a name that have my given string as a part of its name.
I have a bit of problem as it seems my code does not work properly. It seems that it does not find any match.

```
#Read through input(excel) file and convert it to a dataframe
df = pd.read_excel('somename.xlsx')


#Data Cleaning
new_header = df.iloc[0]                 # Taking the first row and put it as headers
df = df[1:]                             # take the rest of your data minus the header row
df.columns = new_header                 # set the header row as the df header
IDs = df['Article No. ']
#print(IDs)
#render to string form 
IDs_string=IDs.to_string() 
#print(IDs_string)


# Search process
import os,shutil
sourcePath ="some path"
destinationPath = "some path"

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(sourcePath):
    for name in files:
        if IDs_string in name:
        shutil.copy(os.path.abspath(root + '/' + name),destinationPath )
```

Comment: I recommend you to use Pathlib. Take a look: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/pathlib.html

Comment: Can you provide us with a sample "somename.xlsx" ?  The code beneath "Search process" works.

Comment: Hi Gerhard, Yes the search process is working fine my problem comes with the if condition which does not do what I want